# Navigation costmap2d

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i get the following error while i run the launch file with

```
roslaunch youbot_navigation_local move_base_local.launch
```

...

```
[ INFO] [1471278418.063178560]: Loading from pre-hydro parameter style
[ INFO] [1471278418.084275407]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1471278418.130269680]:     Subscribed to Topics: hokuyo_laser
[ INFO] [1471278418.162015226]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"

[ INFO] [1471278418.250150436]: Using plugin "footprint_layer"
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
  what():  According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class costmap_2d::FootprintLayer with base class type costmap_2d::Layer does not exist. Declared types are  costmap_2d::InflationLayer costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer costmap_2d::StaticLayer costmap_2d::VoxelLayer
[move_base_node-2] process has died [pid 20334, exit code -6, cmd /home/zeeshan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/move_base/move_base cmd_vel:=move_base/cmd_vel __name:=move_base_node __log:=/home/zeeshan/.ros/log/cbc6dc34-62e4-11e6-aa0c-685d435eb19f/move_base_node-2.log].
log file: /home/zeeshan/.ros/log/cbc6dc34-62e4-11e6-aa0c-685d435eb19f/move_base_node-2*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241755/navigation-costmap2d/) by [Zeeshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27581/zeeshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-08-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-08-15**:
I don't think footprint layer exists any more, obstacle layer takes care of it?  Is this from https://github.com/youbot/youbot-ros-pkg ?   It looks like it hasn't been updated in years.

**Comment by [Zeeshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27581/zeeshan/) on 2016-08-15**:
so please can u tell what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,Zeeshan and lucasw,

I have the same problem when I [Creating a New Layer],(http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20New%20Layer) I got the ERROR:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
  what():  According to the loaded plugin descriptions the classsimple_layer_namespace::SimpleLayer with base class type costmap_2d::Layer does not exist. Declared types are blablabla ...
```

Can you help me, Any opinion is look acceptable.

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**

I have already solved the problem, the cause of error is my format error in `costmap_plugins.xml`.

---

Originally posted by [chengwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/27203/chengwei/) with karma: 51 on 2016-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-27**:
It would probably be nice if you could include what was that "format error", so that future readers can try to avoid it.